# Lua leaderboard in roblox studio

Tags: lua, roblox

I have my leader board but when i run this it gives me this error:

> attempt to index nil with 'leaderstats'

```lua
local me = script.Parent

local function GiveMoney(part)
    local hum = part.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")
    
    if hum then 
        local money = player.leaderstats.Money
        money.Value = money.Value + 1 
        me:Destroy()
    end 
end

me.Touched:Connect(GiveMoney)
```

Comment: The error means in this line `local money = player.leaderstats.Money`  `player.leaderstats` is `nil` i cant say what `player` is or why that would be the case, as you have not included the definition of player in the code shown. my guess is you meant to have that `player` variable actually be the variable `hum`

Comment: @Nifim actually it means that player is nil. as a nil value is indexed with 'leaderstats'

Answer (score 0):

```
local money = player.leaderstats.Money
```

or more specifically `player.leaderstats` causes that error. because `player` is a nil value and indexing nil values is not allowed as it does not make any sense.

Usually Humanoid's parent is a Model, stored as the Player instance's Character property.

Please read the Roblox documentation and search the web to find out how to access leaderboards and players.

Answer (score 0):

```
    local money = player.leaderstats.Money
```

I think you forgot to reference "player" because I can't see player variable anywhere